# The probability of finding a match on a dating site

Tags: probability

I recently came across this sentence in an article I read about the probabilities of finding a match on a dating site:

If men express interest in 60% of the women they see, but women are interested in just 6% of men; this means that 5% of men never receive a match.

Grateful if someone can explain how was the 5% figure reached.

Thx
AH

Comment: What exactly do they mean by "never"?  Given enough time, everyone would get a match eventually.

Answer (score 1):

The Economist article states:

this *dynamic* means that 5% of men never receive a match

(emphasis mine on new word) so I think this 5% is just a site statistic and not derived from the previous data.

Lets say this really was a statistic. Let's calculate the probability that a man has no matches assuming independence of preference (which is definitely not the case on a dating app).

Let $X$ be a random variable representing the number of matches a man gets and $n$ the number of women on the dating app. The probability distribution is

$$\Pr(X = x) = \binom{n}{x} \times 0.036^x \times 0.964^{n - x}$$

We want to solve for the number of women $n$ such that $\Pr(X = 0) = 0.05$ and we get 81.70777.

Therefore, I don't think a dating app gets 82 females so I think there is a lot of missing data to arrive to the solution using these statistics.

Comment: Your formula is wrong: you shouldn't multiply the binomial probability by $0.6$.  Assuming independence, the probability that this man and any particular woman are a match should be $0.6 \times 0.06 = 0.036$.  If there are $n$ women, then the probability of $x$ matches is ${n \choose x} \cdot 0.036^x \cdot 0.964^{n-x}$.

Comment: True, thanks, corrected.

Comment: In addition to the fact that preferences are far from independent, these acceptance probabilities for men and women are only averages, not universally true.  Those people who are likely to be accepted by more potential partners can afford to be pickier.

Comment: Thank you all, very helpful!